# What is Django url app_name and instance_name for?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Whether or not the app_name and instance_name can be anything if i don't use Django template?
I use rest_framework.versioning.NamespaceVersioning and DefaultRouter, Could you please tell me the best practices for my code.

BTW，My company url spec is http://example.org/bookings/v1/ not http://example.org/v1/bookings/.

```
class OOG117Router(DefaultRouter):
    routes = [
        Route(url=r'^{prefix}/v2/detail/{lookup}$',
              mapping={'get': '_detail'},
              name='{basename}-detail',
              detail=True,
              initkwargs={'suffix': 'Detail'}),
        DynamicRoute(url=r'^{prefix}/v2/{url_path}$', name='{basename}-{url_name}', detail=False, initkwargs={}),
        DynamicRoute(url=r'^{prefix}/v2/{lookup}/{url_path}{trailing_slash}$', name='{basename}-{url_name}', detail=True, initkwargs={}),
    ]


oog117_route = OOG117Router(trailing_slash=False)
oog117_route.register(r'todayImage', views.TodayImageViewSet, 'TodayImage')

urlpatterns = [
    path('oog117/', include((oog117_route.urls, 'api'), namespace='v2')),
]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#term-application-namespace
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#term-instance-namespace